# Issue with a specific mysql where query

Tags: mysql

I have a table name messages with column listed below

```
id(PK),encrypted_msg varchar(255) collation is utf8_general_ci
```

When i run below query

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
where `messages`.`encrypted_msg` ='ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2'
```

It doesn't give any result but 'ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2' this value exists for column encrypted_msg

Comment: Run this query and `Select` again `Alter table `messages` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;`...

Answer (score 0):

Try with TRIM or Pattern Matching LIKE Operator IF any space remains before or after your field.

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE trim(`messages`.`encrypted_msg`) LIKE 'ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `messages`.`encrypted_msg` LIKE '%ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
where trim(`messages`.`encrypted_msg`) ='ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2'
```

Comment: still your first query doesn't return any value, anyway i don't want like query. I want exact match.

Comment: Please check this query `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE encrypted_msg like '%\r\n%'` and what it return just tell me.

Comment: it's returning a row but this row doesn't contain string ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2

Comment: Can you give this string which is stored in database So I can check it

Comment: this is the string which is stored in database ON8dmsy9RI2UahR5ydAbsCIDXnrbsoa2